# How do I install pip modules on google compute engine?

Tags: pip, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run some python script using ssh to log into the google compute engine but all the installed pip modules are not found as I do not have permission to the .cache/pip folder in my user is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you fix your home with `sudo chown -R $USER /home/$USER` (where $USER is your login/username)?

Comment: no that doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 10):

You should be running this with the root user.
Also, if you need pip inside your GCP Instance, you can use the following commands:

```
sudo curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
sudo python get-pip.py
```

[[Source](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/)]

Comment: i get the error `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/root/.local'`

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

`sudo` runs this command as an administrator

`apt-get` is the standard package manager used on Debian Linux distributions

`python3-pip` is the package name for pip3

Once installed, you can install PIP modules with:

```
pip3 install MODULE_NAME
```

for example:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Comment: I get `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure there is *one* correct way to do this, but an easy way would be to use the conda python package manager. 
The lighter version of it is [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html). You can get a minimal python installation with pip preinstalled, and virtual environments capability if you need. Assuming you are running on linux and want python 3, you'll have to run

`wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

and then install conda with

`bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

At the end of this process you should have a minimal python installation (that includes pip) and you'll be able to install packages with pip as you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install some basic libraries first -

1. sudo apt-get install bzip2 libxml2-dev

Then install miniconda as given by @teoguso and restart your shell

2. source ~/.bashrc

You can then use conda or pip to install your packages